# Get all the tcp frame on nodejs

Tags: node.js, tcpclient

I'm developing a nodejs Software which namely create a TCP client to read some data.

But for example, if a second data are smaller than the first, the smallest are firstly added to a buffer before the first.

And to avoid that, I would know if it's possible to get all of the frame tcp to process and gather their different data received.

EDIT : Get ACK Byte and SEQ Byte could be a great start.

Sorry for my English and if some information are not understandable, please fill free to ask them.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm trying to check with differents librairies and by checking they differents source code but i'm starting with nodejs and I find anything ^^

Comment: You don't need any library to create a tcp client which connects to a server and request data. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectlistener

Comment: Oh sorry i'm not using a library but a module named "require('net')"
And i would some information about the data receive like Ack byte or Seq byte, It's could be a good start.